# Pandas resample OHLC data to weekly with custom week start/end datetime

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have standard 1m ohlc DataFrame like this:

```
2017-01-02 02:29:00 1.23452 1.23467 1.23452 1.23467 
2017-01-02 02:30:00 1.23464 1.23467 1.23464 1.23465 
2017-01-02 02:31:00 1.23452 1.23465 1.23444 1.23444 
2017-01-02 02:32:00 1.23465 1.23465 1.23447 1.23447 
2017-01-02 02:33:00 1.23447 1.23467 1.23438 1.23464 
2017-01-02 02:34:00 1.23465 1.23465 1.23438 1.23438
```

What I'm trying to do is resample the data to weekly format, but assuming the week starts Tuesday at 10:30 am and ends next Tuesday at 10:29 am.

Is it possible with pandas?